# jQuery text highlighting text nodes break in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, highlight, textnode

I'm currently using this great plugin called **[HighlightJS](https://github.com/tankchintan/highlight-js/blob/master/highlight.js)** for highlighting text on a page when they type in a filter field.

This works great, except for recently we updated from a very old version of jQuery (1.8.2 to 1.11.0) and this no longer works as expected in IE (all versions).  It seems to break up single text nodes into a text-node for each searched item.  This is problematic when I have it constantly adding & removing the highlighting on a `keyup` event.

Here's a screenshot of what used to be a single text node now appearing as multiple in the IE11 inspector.
[image]

---

### I've put together a demo that breaks in the same way in IE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/85yqk/3/)

Any ideas of how to improve this plugin to make it work as it should?  I'll be sure to make a pull request to him on GitHub so others can benefit as well!

Comment: What is `:icontains` shouldn't it be `:contains` ?

Comment: Fiddle seems at first glance to be working fine in my Win 7 IE 10 VM. Anything I should do prove it's not working?

Comment: @Pavlo - `:icontains` is something I made so it's a case-insensative search. The code for that is included below in the fiddle.

Comment: @JasonReid - Do a search, then do another search. Try searching for things in the middle of words.  *"adam" then "male" then "am" then "da"* Keep in mind that the highlighting is what I'm having problems with, not the show/hide of the items.

Comment: Odd. I didn't experience any issues with the highlighting at all. Ran IE10 in a Win 7 VM, and IE9 on another VM. Don't have an IE11 one handy, though, unfortunately.

Comment: So you're saying that after multiple searches in IE (doing the searched I mentioned in my commend above) the text is correctly highlighted in yellow every time?

Comment: Consistently doing a search for "da" will not highlight in the fiddle example I provided. Delete it and then perform the same search again. Remember, this question is about the *highlighting* not the showing/hiding of the items.

Comment: There is actually a bug for this...normalize is broken in IE 11 https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809424/node-normalize-removes-text-if-dashes-are-present#tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and have isolated it to incorrect behavior of the implementation of the native DOM normalize() function in IE11. I've posted some reproduction steps and a workaround on my question:

[Why Does IE11 Handle Node.normalize() Incorrectly for the Minus Symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337498/why-does-ie-handle-node-normalize-incorrectly-for-the-minus-symbol/22337558#22337558)